# Is it a bad practice to write into Guava LoadingCache?

Tags: caching, loading, guava, put

Is it a bad practice to write into guava LoadingCache?
If it is, please give me a reason why it would be a bad practice?

Comment: It is not, e.g. on an update. However, performing a get-compute-put is a bad practice as multiple threads may race. Loading through the cache is a best practice.

Comment: thanks I would load for 70% for 30% I would have to store in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply mix of two approaches.

Either the cache is used as a component storing application data and the application is in charge of controlling both reads and writes, then it makes sense to use the Cache class for it.

Or the cache is used as an interface to some unknown data storage and the application should be completely unaware how the data is loaded, then it makes sense to use LoadingCache. The implementation is usually provided externally by dependency injection.

There can be use cases where the application want to override data in both external source and force the change also in the cache but it's very weird situation and probably wouldn't suite the requirements as the cache would have delay in other application instances anyway.